# Creating final machine learning model: how many times to train?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, svm

I am using a nested cross-validation framework where I optimize the number of features and box constraint parameter for linear SVM using grid search in the inner CV split and assess how good the model is in the outer CV split. Having done this several times, we have now selected a candidate model which we want to test on an held out dataset.

To train the final model, I take all the data which was being used for nested CV, run a single CV to find the final optimum values of number of features and box constraint, and train the final model. However, there will definitely be some instability at this stage with both these parameters varying somewhat depending on how the split was made.

My question is: how many times should I repeat the process of creating a final model? I am currently repeating the process 50 times and then taking the median of optimal hyperparameters; I am then using these median values for creating the final model. Are there better ways of creating the final model that would account for these instabilities?

Comment: This is probably not the kind of question that has an always-optimal theoretical answer, so perhaps you should use further cross-validation (before you touch your hold-out test set) to investigate different approaches to choosing optimal hyper-parameters

Comment: Are you forgetting that each time you perform CV using all the folds, you are supposed to shuffle (randomly permute) all the objects again before they are assigned to new folds before another round of CV?  It's common to run 10 "re-partitions" i.e. shufflings before you run each e.g. 10-fold CV.   This is called "ten 10-fold CV."

Comment: @NXGLogic I am running repeated cross-validation 50 times. During each repeat, a fresh random CV split is generated. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your point?

Comment: I typically don't perform "wrapping", for which the classifier determines feature importance. Rather, I commonly use "filtering" for which external methods are used to determine feature importance.  I also always employ an ensemble of classifiers, and never use SVM by itself.  So I can be of no further assistance.  Your approach will produce feature importance which depends on SVM, so as soon as you use another classifier, they won't be as important.

Comment: Indeed. I am using an aggregate of filter methods for ranking my features too

Comment: @Henry do you have any suggestions on other methods that I could look at? Thanks